# Async hook vs non-async hook to fetch data

Tags: reactjs

I have build a custom hook:

```
const useFirestoreCollection = async (collectionName) => {

    const [documents, setDocuments] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, collectionName));
            const documentsData = [];
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                documentsData.push({
                    id: doc.id,
                    ...doc.data(),
                });
            });
            setDocuments(documentsData);
        };
        fetchData();
    }, []);

    return documents;
};
```

I can use it like this in my component:

```
const [myData, setMyData] = useState([]);

useFirestoreCollection('registeredUsers')
    .then((data) => {
        setMyData(data); // Data Access
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error); // Error
    });
```

I could also delete the async in my custom hook:

```
const useFirestoreCollection = (collectionName) => { <- ASYNC DELETED
    const [documents, setDocuments] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, collectionName));
            const documentsData = [];
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                documentsData.push({
                    id: doc.id,
                    ...doc.data(),
                });
            });
            setDocuments(documentsData);
        };
        fetchData();
    }, []);
    return documents;
};
```

... and use it like this in my component:

```
const myData = useFirestoreCollection('registeredUsers')
```

I have tried to figure it out what is the best approach but was not able to do so.

When should I use the async keyword in my hook and when not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making your hook async is useless in your first case as there's nothing async going directly in your hook, only inside of your `useEffect`.

That make it more difficult to use and makes you duplicate state.

Comment: Thank you! Appreciate your time and answer

Answer (score 2):

I have never seen a situation where a hook should be async. That hook returns a promise now, instead of simply the state & setState functions you want your component to use. This would be a major anti-pattern & complicate the simplicity of hooks terribly.

If you ever need to use async/await functionality within a hook, you declare an async function within. Like you did.

The second approach is clearly the right way to do this.

Comment: Thank you! Im a beginner and sometimes I get overwhelmed by all the different approaches and even google/so/chatgpt cant sort things in my head. your answer made me to understand this. thanks